# Mashup of several songs including "Africa", "No Woman No Cry" and "Sex and Candy"

Tags: identify-this-song, medley

There's this song I once heard which is basically a mashup of a lot of songs in one scale. I'm not sure which scale it was but I think it was C. It's sung by a bunch of guys, and one of them looks kinda like Jack Black.

It has the songs "Africa" (Toto), "No Woman No Cry" (Bob Marley), "Sex and Candy" (Marcy's Playground), and a bunch more.

It would be awesome if someone could tell me what the song is called. I've been looking for it for the past year and I can't find it.

Comment: Are you talking about a medley? or perhaps the axis of awesome song?

Comment: *"I smell sex and candy... Mama, this surely is a dream"* is the song "Sex and Candy" by Marcy's Playground.

Answer (score 4):

Axis of Awesome "Four Chord Song". 
It's not so much the same "key" ( although it is all the same key), it the same chord progression. The joke is that all of the songs consist of the same four chords.

Here is the [song](https://youtu.be/oOlDewpCfZQ)

(As a side note, some of the original songs are in different keys, but all transposed to the same for this song.)